# What version of compat-wireless do I need to install?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, kernel

I have Ubuntu 12.04.1: 3.2.0-31-generic-pae
Wich version of compat-wireless do I need to install?

This is the page: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Download/stable/
The question is: do I just install the latest version of compat-wireless or the version which is closest to the version of the kernel installed on my system?
If the latest version, is it enough to install it alone or do I need incremental installation (all versions in between)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to the page you linked to:

> NOTE: Please be aware that the releases below contain code from the
>   given version of the Linux kernel. Therefore to add functionality, you
>   should select a version that is later than your kernel version.

So, you should get a version that is newer than your kernel. And yes, you only need to install one, not all the versions in between.

What are you trying to do though? The wireless drivers should already be compiled into your Ubuntu kernel. If you are trying to install your wireless card you should follow [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/). You almost certainly do not need to install compat-wireless.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Yes, I read this comment, just basing on this comment both are true: "the most new version" and "version most closest and newer". This why I post question here. I try to use wpa_supplicant for connect to AP manually without network-manager, and here http://superuser.com/questions/487949/unable-to-connect-to-wifi-with-wpa-supplicant/488068#488068 people suggested me it as possible solution to my problem.